# Code on Func and Action

Tags: c#

http://simpleprogrammer.com/2010/09/24/explaining-what-action-and-func-are/

The above code explains in simple terms about Action  and Func.
Still I am not getting what it is for 100%. Or not able to make the code work for me.

```
public void SteamVegetable(Vegetable vegetable, int timeInMinutes)
{
    CookVegetable(vegetable, Steam, timeInMinutes);
}

public void FryVegetable(Vegetable vegetable, int timeInMinutes)
{
    CookVegetable(vegetable, Fry, timeInMinutes);
}

public void BakeVegetable(Vegetable vegetable, int timeInMinutes)
{
    CookVegetable(vegetable, Bake, timeInMinutes);
}

public void CookVegetable(Vegetable vegetable,
   Action<Vegetable, CookingTime> cookingAction,
   int timeInMinutes)
{
    Clean(vegetable);
    cookingAction(vegetable, Minutes.Is(timeInMinutes));
    Serve(vegetable);
}
```

Can someone help me to convert the code from vegetable to numbers and Steam --> Addition, Fry --> Multiplication, Bake --> subtraction when two operands are passed to it.

When I see the code working I can understand it better.

Comment: I'm not sure what your exact **question** is. You could write a method `public static double Add(double x, double y) { return x + y; }` Then inside some other method, you could declare a local variable like so: `Func<double, double, double> f = Add;` After that you could say `var sum = f(2.7, 2.2);`

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong in understanding what you want, but I'll try to answer it. Note, that I omit many complex things in example, like I would use generics instead of plain `int` values, but this will just create redundant complexity in the example.

In example below I just define high-order function, which takes two int values, function, that transforms two values into string (i.e. encapsulate some behavior) and them embrace this result into enclosing and opening tags, one of which is passed in. Note, that I assume you are familiar with lambda notation in C#.

```
ApplyAndPrettyPrint(100, 3, "summ of 100 and 3 is equal to: ", (x,y) => (x*y).ToString("N0"));
ApplyAndPrettyPrint(100, 3, "100 to power 3 is:  ", (x,y) => (Math.Pow(x,y)).ToString("N0"));
ApplyAndPrettyPrint(2, 33, "2 * root of 33 is:  ", (x,y) => (x * Math.Sqrt(y)).ToString("N0"));

public void ApplyAndPrettyPrint( int firstNumber, int secondNumber, string startTag, Func<int, int, string> evaludationFunction) 
{
    string result = startTag;
    result += evaludationFunction(firstNumber, secondNumber);
    result += ";";
    Console.WriteLine (result);
}
```

So that `Func` here is used like a box, with two integers as input and one string as output.

Second example shows how we can pass Action into method, that will be evaluated over some array of numbers. Again, I omit details of IEnumerable interfaces and generics.

```
int[] numbers = new []{ 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
ApplyForEach(numbers, (x) => Console.WriteLine ("square of {0} is {1}", x, x*x));

public void ApplyForEach(int[] numbers, Action<int> someFunction)
{
    foreach (var number in numbers)
    {
        someFunction(number);
    }
}
```

The result will just print squares of integers with some descriptive chars. In other word `Action` is delegate with no outputs. You can think of them as box with some inputs, but with no outputs at all.

Hope that this will do the trick for your understanding. The bottom line is that the only difference between delegate types of `Action` and `Func` is the semantics of the last generic type: in Func it is the returning value, in Action returning value is void, so last generic type just goes to input parameter.

If you find this topic somewhat difficult, Jon Skeet describes delegates within Chapter 5 "Fast-tracked delegates" in his marvelous book "[C# in Depth](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1935182471)"

Answer (score 0):

In the example you provided, `Fry`, `Steam`, and `Bake` are probably supposed to be methods.

Basically, `Action`s and `Func`s let you pass a chunk of code into a method, then execute that chunk of code.

So, you could do

```
public void Foo(Action<int> actionToPerform, int someInt)  
{
    actionToPerform(someInt);
}
```

Then, you could use the `Foo` method with any "chunk of code" that takes an integer.

So,

```
public void Bar() 
{
     Action<int> writeToConsole = i =>  { Console.WriteLine(i); }
     Action<int> writeToSomeLogger = i => { Logger.WriteLog(i); }
     Foo(writeToConsole, 10);
     Foo(writeToSomeLogger, 100);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to throw my example in.. I tried to make it simple, so hopefully this helps.

Take this for example:

```
class MathClass {
    public int Add(int number1, int number2) {
        return DoSomeMathOperation(number1, number2, theAddingIsActuallyDoneHere); // The method "theAddingIsActuallyDoneHere" below is what gets called.
    }

    private int theAddingIsActuallyDoneHere(int number1, int number2) {
        return number1 + number2;
    }

    public int Multiply(int number1, int number2) {
        return DoSomeMathOperation(number1, number2, theMultiplicationIsDoneHere); // The method "theMultiplicationIsDoneHere" is what gets called.
    }

    private int theMultiplicationIsDoneHere(int number1, int number2) {
        return number1 * number2;
    }

    public int DoSomeMathOperation(int number1, int number2, Func<int, int, int> mathOperationFunc) {
        return mathOperationFunc(number1, number2); // This is where you call the method passed in above.
    }
}
```

The above code, can be used like this:

```
MathClass mathClass = new MathClass();

Console.WriteLine(mathClass.Add(5, 10)); // displays 15
Console.WriteLine(mathClass.Multiply(5, 5)); // displays 25
```

Imagine though, that you required a subtraction method. You can create one, via the DoSomeMathOperation function, which expects a `Func<int, int, int>`, which is a function that "takes 2 integer parameters and returns an integer". This would be implemented as follows:

```
Console.WriteLine(mathClass.DoSomeMathOperation(100, 50, (num1, num2) => num1 - num2)); // displays "50"
```

In the above code, you're passing the numbers 100 and 50 into the DoSomeMathOperation method, and those two parameters are being passed into the `Func<int, int, int>`. The result is then returned.

..hopefully that makes sense..